# PSTricks figure turned 90 degrees

Tags: pstricks, rotating

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\RPut(#1)#2{%
  \rput[r]{90}(!#1 1980 sub 2 div 0){#2 \quad}
  \rput[l]{90}(!#1 1980 sub 2 div 0){\quad #1}
}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.78}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-2.9)(14.7,1.3)
  \psaxes[
    labels = none,
    Dx = 2,
    dx = 1,
    Ox = 1980,
    yAxis = false
  ]{->}(15,0)
  \RPut(1980){Lake Placid}
  \RPut(1984){Sarajevo}
  \RPut(2006){Torino}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If I compile using `xelatex` everything is fine but if I compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` the figure is rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

How do I compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` but without getting the rotation?

Comment: In this case, I'm much more inclined to think it is XeLaTeX's bug—perhaps a well placed `\ifxetex` could do the trick?

Comment: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi FDE (Frequently Done Errors) no 5.

Comment: @SeanAllred: it has _nothing_ to do with `XeTeX` itself, it is a `ghostscript` feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it is related to the already known problem "auto rotation" done by `ps2pdf`. Therefore you need to pass `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` key-value to `ps2pdf`. If you are using Windows, use `#` instead of `=` because `=` has a special meaning for batch files in Windows.

### MWE

The following is the minimal working example to mimic your problem. Make sure you set `showgrid=false` to let auto rotation work.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,2)
    \rput{90}(2,1){Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Without `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` (for non-Windows) or without `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` (for Windows), you will get the following output.

[image]

With `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` (for non-Windows) or with `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` (for Windows), you will get the following output.

[image]

### More about Windows

In my experience, both `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` and `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` work on Windows. Let me know if you get different thing as I am using Windows 7. Probably it does not work on older Windows.