# Rotatebox in eso-pic background rotates whole page with scrbook, but not in pdfLaTeX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, rotating, eso-pic

I am using the `eso-pic` package to create a draft sign in the background of my document (`scrbook`-class). The sign is rotated 45° on the page. Everything works fine. I use `TeXLive` and `Kile` with `Suse 12.3`.

Since I need `TikZ` and `pgfplots` in my document I use `LaTeX` (`latex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode '%source'`) -> `DVItoPS` (`dvips -o '%S.ps' '%S.dvi'`) -> `PStoPDF` (`ps2pdf '%S.ps' '%S.pdf'`) to create the pdf.

Now I have to additionally insert a draft-copyright notice on the left hand side of every page. I do produce it the same way I did with the original draft-symbol. But each `\part{title}` titlepage is put in landscape mode in the pdf-viewer. This does not happen when I compile my MWE with `pdfLaTeX` (`pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode '%source'`). It also doesn't happen with `scrreprt`.

The `LateX`-result is:
[image: LaTeX result:]

The `pdfLaTeX` result is:

[image: pdfLaTeX-result:]

Using the `rotating`-package a similar behaviour was found in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135214/rotating-ends-up-turning-the-whole-page-sometimes). It was said that by @Mico `graphicx` package is not intended to be used together with dvips; it should only be used by a TeX engine/format that produces pdf format directly. Is this the problem here also? The workaround mentioned in the thread does not work in my case. Is there any other way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{type1cm,eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
\setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
\put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
% Draft
%\makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.75}% <- it doesn't happen here
%{\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\selectfont{Draft}}}}%
% Copyright
\makebox(-500,-0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.75}% <- it does here
{\fontsize{0.7cm}{0.7cm}\selectfont{Draft \textcopyright Copyright \the\year{} - Copyright owner}}}}
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Part 1}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-4]

\part{Part 2}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: ps2pdf/ghostscript tries to be clever and autorotates the page. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126874/2388. And you don't need to use the latex+dvips-way for tikz and pgfplots. pdflatex will work fine with them.

Comment: For sake of completeness: `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None '%S.ps' '%S.pdf'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer this did the trick: `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None '%S.ps' '%S.pdf'`