# PSTricks rotation driven by auto-pst-pdf

Tags: pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

This looks like the same problem as that one tackled in [PSTricks figure turned 90 degrees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126859/pstricks-figure-turned-90-degrees), only with some twist. The following MWE does not give the rotation:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
  \psframe*[linecolor = red](0,0)(9,1)
  \rput{90}{Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
```

I'm compiling the above on Windows Xp with MikTeX 2.9, using the `pdfLaTeX` engine, and with the parameter `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` passed on to `ps2pdf` via my text editor (`WinEdt 8`) -- even though this is alreaady done by the `auto-pst-pdf` defaults. The `pdfLaTex` engine is passed the parameter `-shell-escape`.

There is no page rotation, but neither is text rotation. Nonetheless, the red box *is* rotated 90 degrees, which I wasn't expecting nor I want to. What can be wrong about it?

Comment: I assume, the output is as desired if compiled with `latex` only?

Comment: The canvas is too small.

Comment: I haven't tried because I need the crop facility that auto-pst-pdf "embeds".

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood: That's fixed automatically in the `auto-pst-pdf` processing. Nonetheless, I have changed it to `\psframe*(0,0)(2,1)` inside a `\begin{pspicture}(-9,-9)(9,9)` and the problem remains.

Comment: @Marcos: with MiKTeX, as far as I know, the switch should be `--enable-write18`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing -dAutoRotatePages#/None in winedt doesn't help, as auto-pst-pdf calls ps2pdf independently. So you musst tell auto-pst-pdf to add this option. The main problem is the # which you can't use directly in tex options. There are perhaps better ways but this here seems to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begingroup
\catcode`\#=11
\gdef\noautorotate{-dAutoRotatePages#/None}
\endgroup

\usepackage[pspdf=\noautorotate]{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
  \psframe*[linecolor = red](0,0)(9,1)
  \rput{90}{Marienplatz}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That made it. Furthermore, you nailed the problem I was having with passing that parameter to `ps2pdf` through the `auto-pst-pdf` key-value system.

Answer (score 3):

It has been documented in `auto-pst-pdf` documentation.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages=/None}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,2)
  \psframe*[linecolor = red](4,2)
  \rput{90}(2,1){cyanide-based food}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason unknown to me, this one didn't work on my system. It may work on a Windows platform newer than Xp, though.

Comment: This answer was posted at 17:52:19.

Comment: Will we ever know your real name? :) +1 anyway :)

Comment: @cmhughes: I lost my self-confidence. :-)