# latex reflection and rotation

Tags: reflection

I'm using reflection and rotation from the graphics package. Depending on the number of characters I get an unwanted landscape output in the PDF file. [latex->dvips->ps2pdf]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% comment A out
REFLECTION\\% A
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% comment out B or C
\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{-1}[1]{REFLECTION}}%%%%% B
%\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{-1}[1]{REFLECTIONXX}}%% C
\end{document}
```

Comment: this will be a setting in your viewer to "guess" the orientation of the page, you need to turn it off (probably called something like "auto rotate") in the viewer preferences.

Comment: thanks for your response but it doesn't help. Compiling with PDFlatex gives the desired result but for my project I have to use latex->dvips->ps2pdf

Comment: I put the suggested line into teh latex file but it didn't help.

Comment: All my available PDF viewers returned a landscape file.

Comment: can you try the autorotate flag in the ps2pdf commandline as explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126859/pstricks-figure-turned-90-degrees (help from egreg to find that:-)

Comment: Thank you; it's not a Latex problem but a ps2pdf one. The link was very helpful.