# psbook, psnup and pstops put to a4 (instead of leaving them landscape) blank pages, and behave differently on two different computers

Tags: windows, ps

I have a .tex file that I compile with `latex` to a .dvi file. Using `dvips` (and ps2pdf if I want a pdf) allows me to see the typesetted document text.ps, and I am happy with it.

Now, I want each page of this document to be "converted" to a5, and each pair of pages put on a landscape a4 paper for printing (not in the following order the page 1 and 2 on 1st booklet page, then page 3 and 4 on second booklet page, for printing and later assembling matters).

I think that this should be realized with the following command lines combo :

```
psbook text.ps text_temp1.ps
psnup -2 text_temp1.ps text_temp2.ps 
pstops.exe 2:0@1,1@1U(21cm,29.7cm) text_temp2.ps text_booklet.ps
ps2pdf  text_booklet.ps text_booklet.pdf
```

Yes the pages are in the right order : on page one of the booklet I have the real first page on the left and the real last page on the right, then on page two of the booklet I have something else etc, perfect for assembling, but the rest doesn't work :

- *blank pages are put in a4, not in landscape ; for this I tried to add `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` in the `ps2pdf` but this doesn't give the orientation I need.
- also, on another PC (with same version of all involved commands, OS etc) I have the same issue as the previous point but also another one : the landscape document seems a little too big (small overflow) for the landscape-a4 format when converted to pdf.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Remark : I am under windows 10, last MikTex up to date, and all psutils commands are from GnuWin32 :
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/psutils.htm
Under a mac I don't have the blank pages being in a4 portrait and not landscape issue.

Comment: It crash !?!?!  Try `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126874/14500).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thx  `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` worked, but does't give what I thought it would give, my bad. So my first problem remains : all the non blank pages are a4 landscape and all blank pages are a4 portrtrait when I'd would like them to be also a4 landscape.

Comment: A blank page is just a blank page (landscape or portrait does not matter).

Comment: It does matter. When opening the pdf and scrolling through it, everything looks fine in landscape except blank pages that are in portrait a4, which, besides looking awful, doesn't look serious at all. Also, it's not at all how it is supposed to look.